# Creating a Do Loop to Cycle through Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am just learning VBA for Excel. I am watching a series of tutorials and there is an exercise where I have to select each worksheet in a workbook and hide it using .visible = False. Here is the code:

```
Sub doloop()

Worksheets("Introduction").Activate

Dim ws As Worksheet

ws = ActiveSheet

Do Until ws.Visible = False
ws.Visible = False

Loop


End Sub
```

It's saying that the object on the Do line is not a valid object. How do I fix this?

Comment: You would use a `For Each` loop. But you can't hide all the sheets in a workbook, at least one sheet must always be visible.

Comment: Also objects like a worksheet need the `set` keyword when assigning a value.

Comment: (side note, hopefully your tutorial is not suggesting a `Do` loop. If it is, probably best to find a new tutorial).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46942603/hide-or-unhide-all-excel-sheets-without-looping

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  'Note: at least 1 sheet must be visible at all times, in this case we choose the first sheet
  if ws.index = 1 then
    ws.visible = true
  else
    ws.visible = false
  end if
next
```

A smaller, yet more advanced alternative, is:

```
Dim ws as worksheet
For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  ws.visible = ws.index = 1
next
```

Comment: It would probably be better to use `.Worksheets` instead of `.Sheets` as `.Sheets` can also refer to chart objects. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets

Comment: @braX Wow never knew that! Thanks 